# How to bind a combobox having an item as a datagrid in wpf? The ComboBox itself is a part of a Datatemplate

Tags: mvvm, binding

I have a TabControl generating some tab items following the MVVM pattern using WPF.
The TabControl ItemTemplate i.e. for each of the tab items that is generated, I have a combobox that should show some data from a different list. **This list is not the same as the bound object of the Tab Item itself.**

For eg: If a tabitem is bound to a address object the combobox should show data from a state list and show the state present in the address object as the selected item.

**The Combo box is having only one item as a datagrid which is bound to the state list**

The problem is that all data is being shown in all sections but the combo box simply wouldnt show the data. Surprisingly, the Combobox when taken out of the TabControl DataTemplate works fine....

Below is the code both outside and inside the tabcontrol. Some suggestions please !!!

------This one is outside the Tabcontrol and works perfectly--------------

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedState}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEditable="True" Margin="50,55,0,61" Height="27" Width="193">
                    <ComboBoxItem TextSearch.Text="{Binding SelectedState}">
                        <ContentControl>
                            <DataGrid SelectedIndex="{Binding StateSelectedIndex}" ItemsSource="{Binding StateData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = [Action SelectionChanged]">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="StateName" Binding="{Binding StateName}" />
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
```

----This one is inside the TabControl ---------

```
   <TabControl Margin="3,3,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="752" Height="255" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Addresses}" SelectedIndex="{Binding WhichAddressTab}" >
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    ...................................
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl>
                              ..........................
                                <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedState}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEditable="True" Margin="108,3,0,1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" Width="147">
                                    <ComboBoxItem TextSearch.Text="{Binding SelectedState}" >
                                        <ContentControl>                                                
                                            <DataGrid SelectedIndex="{Binding StateSelectedIndex}" ItemsSource="{DynamicResource StateData}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = [Action SelectionChanged]">
                                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="StateName" Binding="{Binding StateName}" />
                                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                                            </DataGrid>
                                        </ContentControl>
                                    </ComboBoxItem>
                                </ComboBox>
                             ...........................
                        </Grid>
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
```

---

I have tried searching and have understood the problem is with the databinding within a datatemplate, but have been unable to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is with your binding. The DataContext inside of the DataTemplate is for a single element (from the collection bound to the ItemsSource). Meaning that you can't access properties that are directly on the ViewModel itself.

To work around this, you can name the TabControl for example, and convert your bindings inside of the DataTemplate to use ElementName bindings. Another solution, if you have your ViewModel defined as a Static Resource, is to bind directly to the resource, and use the Path to specify the property to which you want to bind.

Hope this helps :)